# Disable selected anchor button on click in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my `laravel` application `foreachloop` rendring multiple button i want that disable or remove only that button which is clicked so i tired this piece of code

```
@foreach()
         <a onclick="remvebtn()" class="btn">My Button</a>
        @endforeach
```

javascript

```
   function remvebtn(){
 
     $(this).removeAttr("onclick");
}
```

but it is not helpful

Comment: you should try passing class except of onclick

Comment: not worked i tryed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple way of removing the onclick event from a button, once it is clicked:

```js
function remvebtn(btn){
   console.log(btn.textContent)
   btn.onclick=null;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="remvebtn(this)" class="btn">My Button1</a><br>
<a onclick="remvebtn(this)" class="btn">My Button2</a><br>
<a onclick="remvebtn(this)" class="btn">My Button3</a><br>
<a onclick="remvebtn(this)" class="btn">My Button4</a>
```

Or, you can also do it like this:

```js
document.body.onclick=ev=>{
  let btn=ev.target;
  if (btn.classList.contains("btn")){
   ev.preventDefault();
   console.log(ev.target.href);
   btn.classList.remove("btn");
   btn.removeAttribute("href");
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="target1" class="btn">My Button1</a><br>
<a href="2nd_target" class="btn">My Button2</a><br>
<a href="third_one" class="btn">My Button3</a><br>
<a href="and_fourth" class="btn">My Button4</a>
```

Comment: i am very thankful to you it is great and worked for me but i want to know is threre any property in which i remove clicked button mean if user clicks My "My Button1" it should be removed?

Comment: oh thanx i have found btn.remove() and it is worked